# How to get an image to slide from one side of page to the other with jquery or javascript? Just like on thepiratebay.se

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is something i've been seeing alot in slides or on page when scrolling. Moving images. How can I do this with jquery or some simple javascript just like on thepiratebay.se? My idea was a car sliding from one side of the page to the other.

I know jquery can do this with animate() but I dont see any examples of something sliding across the page like on thepiratebay.se

Can anyone pintoint where they use this technique. I'm not sure what js they are using for this cant find it.

Src: http://thepiratebay.se

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript? This can be done by CSS!

Here have a smooth moving kitty.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/cpt778jv/)

**html**

```
<img id="pic" src="tomato"/>
```

**css**

```
#pic {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 2s;
  animation: myfirst 2s;
  position: absolute;
  right: 80%;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  from {right: 10%;}
  to {right: 80%;}
}

@keyframes myfirst {
  from {right: 10%;}
  to {right: 80%;}
}
```

Comment: Persijn, I've looked into css animation and I don't think its as smooth or as customizable as in jquery, I prefer Dom's example. Maybe you could post an snippet of something similar with CSS3 to compare?

Comment: @Tim here is an update with come css. This is a simple example you can do a lot more with CSS animations. Here are some really good animations and css: http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/animation-with-css3-712437

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example.

CSS:

```
#b {
position: absolute;
top:50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<img id="b" src="example.jpg"/>
```

Jquery

```
function moveRight(){
    $("#b").animate({left: "+=300"}, 2000,moveLeft)
}

function moveLeft(){
    $("#b").animate({left: "-=300"}, 2000,moveRight)
}

$(document).ready(function() {

   moveRight();

});
```

this will move it left to right constantly.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Great example Dom, I was able to make the car move off the page then slide back in with your example! Thanks!